# Manually set sentence boundaries in Spacy

Tags: python, spacy, sentence

Suppose I know ahead of time the *character-level* sentence boundaries in a document:

```
text = "The cat chased the mouse. The mouse ran away."
boundaries = [(0, 25), (26, 45)]
for start, end in boundaries:
    print(text[start:end])
```

Is there a way that I can tell Spacy to use these boundaries? From what I can gather in the official [docs](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#sbd-custom) and [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52458404/custom-sentence-segmentation-in-spacy), the hooks provided seem more suited to support custom stateless *rules* that apply at the word (token) level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put sentence boundaries at arbitrary characters - spaCy won't let you put a sentence in the middle of a token.

What you can do is iterate over tokens and use `token.idx` (the character index of the token) to apply your boundaries by finding the token that lines up with your boundary index. You'll have to figure out a policy for what to do if token boundaries don't line up with your values, whether that's throwing an exception or dealing with it somehow.

Comment: Thanks @polm23. Is it possible to set the boundaries ahead of time, and let the tokenizer, entity recognizer work within those constraints? I think I am talking myself into making each sentence its own `Doc` instance. Then it might be nice to merge the sentence `Doc`s back into one `Doc.`

Comment: You can set sentence boundaries before the parser runs and it will respect them. Currently there is a bug where if you set some but not all sentence boundaries they might get overwritten when they shouldn't, though it seems kind of hard to trigger. But yeah, if you're that confident in your boundaries it sounds like you might be better off treating them as separate docs.